# I am having trouble outputting data to a dynamically generated table with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects, vue-component

I am generating a table dynamically with VueJS and everything works fine when it comes to the creation of the `<th>` elements.

To set them up, I have a Vue component, which is getting outputted by calling the addRow function. It uses templates with values which are taken from two input fields, namely "Please add service" and "Please enter price". The values are added to an array on the data object and they are dynamically cleared so that more items can be added.

When I console log the array, what I have input and stored in the array as an object remains, regardless how many items. Their textual content is simply not in the new table rows.

The only clue I have after quite a bit of research is that the elements might not be reactive. However, they have getters and setters, which means that it is not likely. Another idea I had was, that it is related to scope.

Please advice further.

Here is my full code: https://codepen.io/MrYY/pen/PeJjZy

And here are the Vue instance and Vue component

```
Vue.component('table-row', {
    template: '\<tr>\
    <th>\
      {{ this.name }}\
    </th>\
    <th>\
      {{ this.price }}\
    </th>\
    \</tr>\
  ',
  props: ['row']
 })

var app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        companyName: "Company Name",
        repName: "Representative's name",
        phone: "+359-00-000-0000",
        newService: "Please add service",
        price: "Please enter price",
        services: [

        ]
    },

    methods: {

        addRow: function () {
            this.services.push({
                servicesName: this.newService,
                price: this.price
            });
            this.newService = "Please add service";
            this.price = "Please enter price";
        }
    }



})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `service` as a props for your component

```
<tr is="table-row" v-for="service in services" :service="service">

Vue.component('table-row', {
    template: '\<tr>\
    <th>\
      {{ service.servicesName }}\
    </th>\
    <th>\
      {{ service.price }}\
    </th>\
    \</tr>\
  ',
  props: ['service']
 })
```